# передача файлов на сервер

Tags: javascript, php, html

Возникла такая проблема с передачей файлов на сервер. При передачи файла с названием на английском языке все работает отлично. Но если пытаюсь передать файлы с названием на русском языке, то при передачи файла его название меняется на какие-то символы. Как это исправить?

```
<label><strong>Загружаемые файлы</strong></label><br><br>
<label><input type="file" name="myfile[]" class="js-fileinput" /></label>
```

php

```
$upload_file= urldecode($_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],"$folder/$upload_file");
```

Comment: попробуйте urldecode() - php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 1):

Пропустите имя файла, которое вы получаете из $_FILES через функцию urldecode: $fileName = urldecode($fileName);

Если с настройками веб-сервера, с mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8") и прочим не получится, тогда сделайте так: 
`$fileName = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'Windows-1251', 'UTF-8');` и получите вместо С‚Р°Р±Р»РёС†С‹ нормальное отображение имени - таблицы. $text - это строка, содержащая искаженное имя файла.

Значит проблема скорее всего с редактором кода, в котором вы создавали и сохраняли файл таблицы. Он сохраняет в другой кодировке.

Comment: У меня не работает, мб я что-то не так делаю?
В своем посте я написал, как обрабатываю с помощью php, а то здесь неудобно

Comment: скопируйте нормально имя файла на русском и отдельно, как получается в виде символов

Comment: и если вы загружаете только один файл, то лучше убрать [] из имени (myfile[]). это избавит вас от ненужной вложенности, когда будете работать с массивом $_FILES. лучше так: <input type="file" name="myfile" class="js-fileinput" />

Comment: на русском: таблицы    ; после: С‚Р°Р±Р»РёС†С‹

Comment: вложенность у меня для случая, если будут загружать несколько файлов, для этого у меня еще js класс висит js-fileinput

Comment: у вас не настроена кодировка на utf-8. укажите либо в html (<meta charset="utf-8">) либо с помощью php: mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); установленную кодировку можно узнать с помощью echo mb_internal_encoding();

Comment: Не помогло, через echo у меня выводит UTF-8 =(

Comment: а кодировка самого файла php у вас без ВОМ? может быть еще из-за этого. и настройки веб-сервера тоже проверьте, если апач, попробуйте в .htaccess задать AddCharset UTF-8 .php

Comment: без BOM, попробовал добавить кодировку в .htaccess тоже не помогло=(

Comment: а на вашем хостинге включена поддержка мультибайтовой кодировки?

Comment: не нашел, как ответить в чате, я на openserver делаю

Comment: а винда какая? выполните phpinfo(), там подробная информация будет обо всем

Comment: это тоже не помогло, проблема немного в другом, имя файла выводится верно даже на русском языке, оно меняется именно после копирования move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],"$folder/$upload_file");

Comment: если я до move_uploaded_file сделаю echo $upload_file; , то мне все выведет корректно

Comment: тогда пробуйте так: `$upload_file = mb_convert_encoding( $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i], "UTF-8" );` А urldecode не нужно.

Comment: неа, а можете скинуть код, который у вас эти действия выполняет корректно и с какими типами файлов, мб я что-то упускаю, не знаю уже=(